# Concentration Ratio - Real Estate Appraisals/Valuations

Tags: competition, monopolistic-competition, property

with reference to **"Market Structures"**, how can you work out whether your industry is operating in an *Oligopoly/monopolistic/...*-environment if there is insufficient data?

I'm specifically examining the concentration ratio of Property Appraisal firms in France. But without publicised figures regarding the number of Property Appraisals per firm, per year, how can one talk about an industry without knowing its competitive landscape? Relevant data is made available by a few firms, but not all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem. What is it exactly that you want to do? You can talk about an industry without talking about its competitive landscape. (E.g.; carmakers have long supply chains.) If you want to talk about their competitive landscape, what is it exactly that you want to say? Saying "it is an oligopolistic industry" is unclear, there is no set definition for "oligopolistic", there are varying degrees. So what exactly is it that you really want to do?

Comment: I want to analyse the market structure of the real estate appraisal industry, to assess the competitive performance of relevant firms against one another. I aim to do this with the help of Porter's Five Forces... but it seems important for me to establish what the market structure is to start.

Comment: As I wrote in my first comment, market structure is something of a spectrum, there are no clearcut lines between the categories. Seems like this is why Porter may be useful.

Comment: So based off Porter's Five Forces, could I then extrapolate that the industry is on the market structure spectrum, with both oligopolistic and monopolistic competition traits ? Would you recommend any other frameworks for analysing an industry's market structure ?

Comment: Sorry, I am no expert on Porter's.